# How I can use a Label(Large 12 words) in my ion-input

Tags: ionic-framework

Thas is the code

```
      <ion-list [inset]="">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label class="ion-text-wrap">4.5.1.En los terrenos que corresponden a esta entrevis ta
            ¿existe HOY alguna de las siguientes especies?
            </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ue7O.png)

fix this problem or allow longer characters to be entered in the ion-input
:D